# Redirecting everything to index.php and stripping last slash

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mime-types

i currently have the code below to redirect all requests (except files) to the index.php unfortunately i cannot get my script to work because of some strange mime type error happening when my url ends with a slash.

The strange part is that my code output is the same with both urls but the error appears only in the / ending one.

So i'm looking for a way to redirect all request as it's working right now just withouth slash or just solve the mime type issue, but i have no idea what is causing it...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  # Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
  RewriteEngine On

  # Redirect /index.php to / (optional, but recommended I guess)
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php
  RewriteRule ^index.php/?(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]

  # Run everything else but real files through index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

QSA = Query String Append, it will preserve query string.

If `index.php` is a file, and that file exists then it'll not pass on the test, so there's no need of first `RewriteCond` block.

Comment: I still have the mime type issue

Comment: Explain that issue. what mime-type it brings?:

Comment: text/plain... all of the attached files, you can see an exaple here
http://karimcossutti.com/newsite/lab/

Comment: The problem isn't the routing, the problem is your HTML. You need to poing `.js` and `.css` files to root `/` or use `<base/>` tag to tell browser where's your `/`.

Answer (score -1):

You can't have a URL end in a slash.
If I understand you right and the URL you are using is

```
www.server.com/index.php/[more here]
```

that is incorrect URL syntax. You can only follow the .php with a get string -

```
www.server.com/index.php?some_url_param=some_value
```

someparametershere

Comment: My url is www.server.it/something/somethingElse"/"<-- problematic slash

The htaccess rule transforms it in www.server.itindex.php?/something/somethingElse (slashes are correctly encoded)

Comment: Right. You can't have a directory inside a file, that makes no sense. Anything after the "?" needs to be in encoded variable format- if you are trying to pass a directory name for a script to use then it needs to be something like "index.php?directory=/something/somethingElse" where the slashes are correctly encoded as you previously said. There is probably a better way to do it than this.

Comment: It's actually fairly common to do this with apache anymore.  I'm not sure when it started, or if it's supported on other web servers or not, but this actually works perfectly fine at least on Apache.  Which is to say, `/index.php/foo/bar` correctly routes you to `index.php` and you can check the `REQUEST_URI` from there.

Comment: i am getting the value with $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] and it is returning the value correctly